# Issue about generic constructor reference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Please, consider the following code:

```
abstract class AbstractBusEvent { }

interface EventBusListener<T extends AbstractBusEvent> {
    (event: T): void;
}

class EventBus {
    public register<T extends AbstractBusEvent>(eventConstructor: { new (...args: any[]): T }, 
        listener: EventBusListener<T>): void {
    }
}
```

And now

```
class TempEvent extends AbstractBusEvent {}
class MyEvent extends AbstractBusEvent {}

const bus: EventBus = new EventBus();
bus.register(TempEvent, (e: MyEvent)=>{});//LINE X
```

The problem is that at LINE X - I don't get any errors, although, as you see it is wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I expect to get error, because the right code is `bus.register(TempEvent, (e: TempEvent)=>{});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TempEvent` and `MyEvent` are identical. There is no difference whatsoever. So it is correct that there is no type difference hence you can mix both in the `register` method. However if you add member fields, then the tscompiler will complain e.g.

```
class TempEvent extends AbstractBusEvent {
    props: string;
}
class MyEvent extends AbstractBusEvent {
    props: number;
}
```

Comment: I am just trying to understand what you say - how can they be identical if they are different classes? Or TypeScript considers different classes by checking their equality?

Comment: @Pavel_K You have objects in Javascript. Even if you name the objects differently, if they have the exact same structure then they are identical.